# Javascript files not loading in Wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, css, wordpress

I am trying to load Javascript and css files for my WP plugin. I have added this code to my functions.php file but the scripts are not being loaded on the page.

I am teaching myself PHP so I am sure I could missing something elementary.

```
function Gc_Js_Ins() {
    if (!is_admin()) {

    $Gc_Js_Ins_url2 = plugins_url('js/jquery_ujs.js', __FILE__);
    $Gc_Js_Ins_url3 = plugins_url('js/js_ws.js', __FILE__);
    $Gc_Js_Ins_url4 = plugins_url('js/bootstrap.min.js', __FILE__);
    $Gc_Js_Ins_url5 = plugins_url('js/event_list.js', __FILE__);

    wp_register_script('gc_jquery_ujs', $Gc_Js_Ins_url2);
    wp_enqueue_script('gc_jquery_ujs');

    wp_register_script('gc_js_ws', $Gc_Js_Ins_url3);
    wp_enqueue_script('gc_js_ws');

    wp_register_script('gc_bootstrap_min', $Gc_Js_Ins_url4);
    wp_enqueue_script('gc_bootstrap_min');

    wp_register_script('gc_event_list', $Gc_Js_Ins_url5);    
    wp_enqueue_script('gc_event_list');

    }
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_script', 'Gc_Js_Ins');

function Gc_Css_Ins(){
if (!is_admin()){

wp_register_style('Gc_js_ws','//www.gc.com/assets/js_ws.css');
wp_register_style('Gc_bootstrap','//www.gc.com/assets/bootstrap.min.css');

wp_enqueue_style('Gc_js_ws');
wp_enqueue_style('Gc_bootstrap');

    }
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_style','Gc_Css_Ins');
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a misspelling in one line. Instead of:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_script', 'Gc_Js_Ins');
```

There should be:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'Gc_Js_Ins');
```

Moreover you have to use the same hook to enqueue both js and styles, so in the last line instead of:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_style','Gc_Css_Ins');
```

There should be similarly like above:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'Gc_Css_Ins');
```

Comment: Thanks @Grzegorz-Pawlik I didn't realize that was misspelled. When I made the correction my Javascript still isn't working.

Comment: With no working do you mean they are still not being called? Maybe there is a problem with their paths?

Comment: I also noticed that there isn't a hook called "wp_enqueue_style" I didn't realize I was supposed to use the "wp_enqueue_scripts", so I updated that. I am new to this site. Should I worry about posting the new code that doesn't work?

Comment: You are correct the javascript is not being called for my page.

Comment: I have tested it and it works for me. Have in mind that you have !is_admin() condition which means the scripts are not being called when you are logged in as an admin. Are you sure you are correctly logged out?

Comment: I must be missing something else because I still can't get it to work on my website. I'm glad it worked for you that means something is correct. I will have to keep looking for what is wrong.

I did remove the !isadmin and that didn't help.